# Why does loading my own ~/.Xmodmap freeze my desktop on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, xmodmap

I created a modified Xmodmap file in my home directory. When I try to load it with.

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

or on startup, it freezes my desktop for several minutes. It wasn't the case on my Xenial Desktop.

Comment: Try this workarounds [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390198/275123](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390198/275123) and let us know if there's any change.

Comment: @Dokan yes this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackexchange user [@kontrollantaren](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/249524/kontrollanten) show us [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390198/275123) how it can be solved in some situations:
Before initiating custom xmodmap config:

```
# Store default xmodmap 
$ xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap.default 

# Backup your custom xmodmap
$ mv ~/.Xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap.bak

# Make a diff between default and custom xmodmap, and store the diff as .Xmodmap
$ diff ~/.Xmodmap.bak ~/.Xmodmap.default | grep '<' | tr '<' ' ' > ~/.Xmodmap
```

Also the user [@C.T.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/152821/c-t) proposes [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257038/275123) using xkb instead of xmodmap.

Offtopic: I cannot comment but when answered the question it was placed as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

When `xmodmap` runs, it calls the `XChangeKeyboardMapping` function once for every modified key, generating `MappingNotify` events each time and slowing down the system. An alternative would be to use `xkb` instead which does not have this problem.

Just modify the file in `/usr/share/X11/symbols/pc` which has the following layout

```
key <LCTL> {    [ Super_L       ]   };
key <LWIN> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
...
```

Now to make these changes take effect simply clear the `xkb` cache by using

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

Comment: I did
`rm -rf` 
then restart and I don't have my keyboard at all. No login nothing is possible.
So that is not the answer.