# xmodmap locking MATE desktop

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mate, xmodmap

20.10 with MATE desktop up to date as of today.

I want to disable one of the special keys on my keyboard. The calculator button is positioned where I will too often press it while picking up the keyboard and I'll get several instances of the calculator.

Using

```
 xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

I then locate the Calculator key

```
 keycode 148 = XF86Calculator NoSymbol XF86Calculator
```

And clear the fields after the '='

```
 keycode 148 =
```

There are a number of entries in this form so I'm *assuming* it is syntactically okay.

Save the file and then

```
 xmodmap .xmodmap
```

The whole desktop freezes.

I can access the system via SSH and view the journal but see nothing of note.

Comment: Does the computer come back after 20 ~ 30 seconds, or does it stay frozen?

Comment: Same as this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060485/why-does-loading-my-own-xmodmap-freeze-my-desktop-on-18-04

Comment: @Matigo -- oof. Yes. Thanks